# How does Facebook handle requests between Home page and Profile page

Tags: ajax, facebook

I am just wondering how facebook manage requests to "my profile page" and "home page" and some other pages that seem to reload just some content.

For example when I am on "my profile page" on facebook, i Hit the home button and the top bar button and chat panel on right side remain intact (they are not reloaded). I have monitored XMLHTTPRequest in webkit console and no ajax is generated, so its not Ajax (i think). Otherwise, if FULL http requests are generated when clicking those links, I thought the full page must be reloaded, I am right? So I have no clue how is this handled. Can you give me a hand please?

Thanks :)

Comment: http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

Comment: Ok, thanks, its html5?? Can you tell me which feature is in use in that situation?? Thanks...

Comment: Thanks I have read it and it was very interesting, I did not know the html5 history api... However I am still a bit confused. I have read the dogs history example http://diveintohtml5.info/examples/history/adagio.html and it uses ajax to refresh the picture. Facebook does NOT use ajax when switching between my profile and home. I still do not understand how those links works. Top bar and chat are not refreshed between requests. Also there's something strange cause In google chrome console, in network TAB, requests are not flushed and when a full http request is made, requests are flushed.

Comment: it performs ajax requests. I just checked and I see those requests (the ones with `?ajaxpipe=1&...` in their URL

Answer (score 0):

It's a type of performance optimization called "quickling", they also use a "pagecache" strategy to reduce the data from server. In the lower level, it depends on javascript perform as a LinkController, which delegate a hyper-link click event and then send an ajax (or use iframe) to request the pagelet data from server, the response will be a json-formed data structure, then javascript will insert the content of current page. Uri in your address bar can be dealled with the hash change event in old browsers and H5's History API (pushState) to manage the history record of browser.